# Is it possible to find out who created a tag in Git?

Tags: git

Commits obviously have an author associated with them; but is it possible to find out which user created a tag on a Git repository?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If it's an annotated tag, then yes. You can `git show` it just like any other object. If it's a lightweight tag, then I don't believe so. Just one of the reasons why you should always annotate the tags you're going to share.

Comment: When I do that with the tag name, it shows me the commit message at the tag position, but no information about the tag itself. Does this suggest that it's not an annotated tag?

Comment: Correct. If it was an annotated tag, `git show $tag` would show you information about the tag first, followed by the commit it's pointing to. If it's a lightweight tag, it just shows the commit.

Comment: this no longer applies to recent git I believe `git show` full details for a lightweight tag I have
Git version - `2.24.3`

Comment: @DiretnanDomnan Please elaborate. Lightweight tags _have no details_. They're just refs in the `refs/tags` namespace, but they point to commits instead of tag objects. This means there are no details to show.

Comment: @LilyBallard Lightweight tags are tags created without the presence of -a, -s, -m arguments right?
Well I created tags like that and was able to use git show

Answer (score 19):

You can use this command to show git tags with date, message and author email:

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname) %09 %(taggerdate) %(subject) %(taggeremail)' refs/tags  --sort=taggerdate
```

This is the result of this command when I launch it on [Material-UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) project:

[image]

Comment: For lightweight tags this method doesn't show the author (as the info is not available).