# Is it possible to see the tagger information for tags in Github?

Tags: git, github, tags

I created a tag for my repo and I see the message, but don't see the tagger info. Is there something I can do to see the tagger info in GitHub?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to find out who created a tag in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770298/is-it-possible-to-find-out-who-created-a-tag-in-git)

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno, thanks but I am looking on how to get the author on Github. I saw how to do this on git, but it looks like it isn't showing up in Github.